# jmerise export give me a syntax error when imported in mariadb but I can't find the syntax error in script

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm creating a sql database using jmersie and mariadb, ehere is my issue when I try to import the sql file in mariadb I get an error #1064 which seems to rely to a syntax error but when I read my sql request I don't see any issue, can you help me ?

here is one of the request leading to an issue :

```sql
#[...]
#------------------------------------------------------------
# Table: piecesinventaire
#------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE piecesinventaire(
        idinventaire      Varchar (50) NOT NULL ,
        nompiece          Varchar (50) NOT NULL ,
        adresseimagepiece Varchar (50) ,
        urlpiece          Varchar ,
        stockpiece        Int NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT piecesinventaire_PK PRIMARY KEY (idinventaire)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
#[...]
```

Comment: Please ALWAYS show the complete error message and not your summary, there is often useful information you decide to miss out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urlpiece` is `VARCHAR` **without** a size, which causes an error

```
CREATE TABLE piecesinventaire(
        idinventaire      Varchar (50) NOT NULL ,
        nompiece          Varchar (50) NOT NULL ,
        adresseimagepiece Varchar (50) ,
        urlpiece          Varchar(10) ,
        stockpiece        Int NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT piecesinventaire_PK PRIMARY KEY (idinventaire)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```